# Why debouce function prints the value differently in textbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

Problem:
In the code below, I tried to type "red" continuously and after 2 seconds, `"red"` appeared in the textbox. Then, after a few seconds, I tried to type "re" continuously. Now, after 2 seconds I got "STACK OVERFLOW DOES NOT ALLOW ME PROVIDE OUTPUT HERE".

Please try it yourself.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import './style.css';
    
    export default function App() {
      const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
    
      
    
    function debouce(fn) {
        let timeout;
      return function() {
        console.log("final", arguments[0])
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, arguments), 1000);
      };
      }
    
      const getvalue = debouce(setInputValue);
    let a = "";
      const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        a = a+ value;
        console.log('targetvalue', a);
        getvalue(a);
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <input onChange={handleChange} value={inputValue} />
          <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
          <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Demo link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nh3ty2

Why? Can anyone explain please how to do it correctly as well

UPDATE: i understood that debouce decorator cannot be altered for the required criteria so im changing from below code

```
function debouce(fn) {
    let a = '',
      timerid;
    return function (e) {
      a = a + e;
      clearTimeout(timerid);
      timerid = setTimeout(function () {
        fn.apply(this, [a]);
        a = '';
      }, 2000);
    };
  }
```

to this

```
function debouce(fn) {
    let timeout;
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, arguments), ms);
  };
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "STACK OVERFLOW DOES NOT ALLOW ME PROVIDE OUTPUT HERE"? Also, debouncing the user input event directly is a bad idea: it's a horrible experience because users cannot see what they're typing. I think what you're looking for is to debounce the _setting/storing_ of a certain data when the user is inputting something.

Comment: Also, I have no idea where you got this debounce function from: if you use the tried and tested methods from [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function), or [lodash.debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce), or the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) or even the [`useDebounce` hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce), then your code works as expected.

Comment: @Terry "redrrede" this is output i got instead of "STACK OVERFLOW DOES NOT ALLOW ME PROVIDE OUTPUT HERE". 
Debouce function is own implementation . Please correct where i am wrong in the code .